# Problems with cyrillic, search on string

Tags: c

I have to write counter of symbols. If I'm looking for `s` in string, `count` is 3, but if I'm looking for Cyrillic (`н`), something wrong. I tried to look for `237` code. This code I found in ASCII table http://ascii.org.ru/ascii.pdf.

How I can fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
  char str[] = "This is a string. нннн";
  char * pch;
  int count = 0;

  pch = strchr(str, 's');

  while (pch != NULL) {
    count++;
    pch = strchr(pch + 1, 's');
  }
  printf("%i", count);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `н` is a unicode character.Maybe [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/unicode.html) will help you.

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether `strchr()` works with `wchar_t` or not. Maybe you can take the array as `wchat _t` and try comparing the ASCII value yourself?

Comment: @justmscs but gcc show me error message: `character too large for enclosing character literal type pch = strchr(str, 'н');`

Comment: What encoding does you C-file have?

Comment: @justmscs: There is at least one system where it doesn't work: http://rextester.com/NZO14263

Comment: @Morpfh ugh, sorry, I don't understand ;(

Comment: Note that last ASCII character has code 127, so `(char)237` isn't in the ASCII.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest switching to `wchar_t` and wide-char functions (`wcschr()`, etc.).

So character data in the program would be stored in 32bit (Linux) or 16bit (Windows) instead of 8bit. This would allow to properly handle all locales.

Also, if You'll need to work with UTF-8 (multibyte strings), `mbstowcs()` should convert data to `wchar_t`.

Full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main () {
  wchar_t str[] = L"This is a string. нннн";
  wchar_t * pch;
  int count = 0;

  pch = wcschr(str, L'н');

  while (pch != NULL) {
    count++;
    pch = wcschr(pch + 1, L'н');
  }
  wprintf(L"%i", count);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why `wprintf` instead of `printf`? It seems superfluous, when printing `int`.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus, true, You can use `printf()`, but from my experience You can't mix reliably ASCII ant WC I/O functions, (because on Linux descriptor is switched to ASCII or WC on first use). And this is a case, where WC I/O is likely to be used anyway. So just in case...

Answer (score 4):

You have to save the C-file with cyrillic encoding.

If file is saved with Unicode, e.g. UTF-8 `н` will be a two byte glyph.

```
0x04 0x3d    (4 61)
```

not

```
0xed         (237)
```

In effect, what your compiler reads when it parses your source file and encounter the line:

```
pch = strchr(str, 'н');
```

is

```
pch = strchr(str, 0x0461);
```

not

```
pch = strchr(str, 0xed);
```

Depending on editor you can usually change encoding of file,  e.g. in Vim

```
set fenc=cyrillic
set fenc=iso-8859-5
etc.
```

Then

```
pch = strchr(pch + 1, 'н');
```

should work as expected. Else you can search for the byte value by 237, but, then file has to be in Cyrillic, all the same, as your input string will have *same encoding as source file*.

Beside that; looking into `wchar_t` is likely the best approach. But then again, all depending on context.